# Objective-C multithreading, what happens when an object gets dealloc while its methods are being executed? (And how to prevent it?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I am writing an app for the iPhone and arrived at this situation.

I have a view controller, myViewController, that will dealloc whenever the user taps the "back" button on the screen. There a thread in the background that communicates with a remote server and may message  a method, updateUI, method in myViewController.

What would happen if the background thread messages updateUI in myViewController, but the user just happened to tapped the "back" button at the right time such that it causes myViewController to dealloc while updateUI is still executing?

My guess is that the dealloc method will run and the app might crash if updateUI ends up using a null pointer. Assuming this is the case, the current solution I have is:

```
[self retain];
// updateUI code here
[self release];
```

I am unsure if this is the best solution, as I feel that this is a common problem when dealing with multiple threads.

Is my assumption correct? If so, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing is known as a "race condition." Race conditions can be difficult to identify in testing, track down once reported, and reproduce because sometimes execution in the debugger can effectively modify how the code is being executed (avoiding the condition that one is trying to reproduce). Race conditions are one of the major pitfalls in concurrent programming - making the area deceptively difficult to do well.

In principle, it is a best practice to minimize the use of shared resources and closely qualify how the sharing is coordinated when implementing concurrency. If an object is shared across multiple threads, it should be retained by each of them to ensure that the object stays in-scope while each thread completes its processing.

Apple has been taking steps to simplify implementing concurrency. This is a good starting point for familiarizing yourself with the topic on iOS.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091

It's also useful to be aware that Objective-C 2.0's properties can support atomic operations (and are atomic by default, thus the nonatomic keyword to disable this default).
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

And, this is the old-school guide to threads (out of favor approach, but still useful background - be sure to be familiar with NSLock).
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i

Answer (score 3):

Whenever some part of your code depends on another, it should retain this dependency until it is not needed. In your case the background worker should retain the controller and only release it when the work is done (or cancelled).

Comment: Don't forget to also fully consider exactly how your various data structures are also ensuring integrity across concurrent reads/writes....  Oh, btw, multithreading is hard. :).

Answer (score 2):

If you `dealloc` **and then nil** your objects then this shouldn't be an issue - you can send messages to `nil` in objective-c.

Alternatively, if you wanted the viewController to get the message and if your targeting iOs 4, you can use blocks and GCD. Blocks auto retain objects and therefore if a block references your viewController, would keep it around for as long as its needed, even if `-(void)dealloc ;` has been called.

[Here](http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/06/27/a-simple-job-queue-with-grand-central-dispatch/) is a decent Block tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your app will crash, likely with something along the lines of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

As far as multithreading, you will want to retain your objects until *everything is done with them* **and** program defensively. Check for the existence of objects before trying to manipulate them.